# Profits vs. losses from stocks, options, and futures: separate, or combined?

Tags: united-states, stocks, tax-deduction, options, futures

Are stocks, options, and futures all considered part of the same basket for tax purposes?

E.g., if one make some **profits** on **stocks** and **losses** on **futures**, does the IRS allow one to deduct the losses from the profits, or are stocks and futures considered completely separate, and **losses** from **futures** can only be deducted from **profits** on **futures**?

I'm asking as an unincorporated sole proprietor. Not incorporated as an LLC or some such.

Comment: Please tag your question with the country you're asking about.

Comment: That feels like a hairy enough question that I'd suggest paying a professional for an answer. I don't ask accountants to write programs; I don't ask the Internet questions that involve interpreting edge cases of law.

Comment: @keshlam You're right, and any advice I get from StackExchange: I always get second and third opinions for from professionals :-)

Comment: @chris-w-rea Thank you for the neat editing and for adding the US tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes, profits and losses from stocks, options, and futures can be combined with each other for tax purposes.  But different tax forms will need to be filled out.

**Long answer:**

For stocks, you would report your profits/losses on [Form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf).  This is mentioned in the [Instructions for Form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8949.pdf):

> Line 1
>
> Enter all sales and exchanges of capital
> assets, including stocks

For options (those that are not Section 1256 contracts), you would report your profits/losses on Form 8949.  This is mentioned in the [Instructions for Schedule D](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sd.pdf):

> Gain or Loss From Options
>
> Report on Form 8949 gain or loss from
> the closing or expiration of an option
> that is not a section 1256 contract but is
> a capital asset in your hands

For futures (and options that are Section 1256 contracts), you would report your profits/losses on [Form 6781](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f6781.pdf) (Gains and Losses From Section 1256
Contracts and Straddles).  According to that form, Section 1256 contracts include futures contracts and certain types of options:

> A section 1256 contract is any:
>
> • Regulated futures contract,
>
> • Foreign currency contract,
>
> • Nonequity option,
>
> • Dealer equity option, or
>
> • Dealer securities futures contract.

So for stocks, options, and futures transactions, you will be filling out Forms 8949 and 6781.  Then you will put the totals from those forms onto [Schedule D](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sd.pdf).  As you can see from Schedule D, short-term profits/losses from Form 8949 are reported on lines 1b, 2, and 3, and profits/losses from Form 6781 are reported on line 4.  On line 7, those totals are combined.

If you have long-term profits/losses from Form 8949, they are reported on lines 8b, 9, and 10, and added up in line 15.

Then lines 7 and 15 are combined in line 16, which is used to fill out Form 1040.  So yes, profits/losses (both short-term and long-term) from stocks, options, and futures can be combined with each other.